# вывести слова в обратном алфавитном порядке

Tags: строки, циклы, pascal, pascalabc.net

дан массив согласных букв. если число, вводимое с клавиатуры больше, чем согласных в слове, то вывести слова в обратном алфавитном порядке. вот часть кода:

```
const mas1=['б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ'];
var s:string;
    i,k,n:byte;
begin
    write('строка: ');
    readln(s);
    write('число: ');
    readln(n);
    for i:=1 to length(s) do
     if s[i] in mas1 then inc(k);
     if k>=n then
       writeln(k,' гласных');
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос то?

Comment: Да и формулировочка хромает... Количество согласных -  в одном слове, а в обратном порядке - много слов.

Comment: Вот оно же?   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463011/

Comment: вопрос: как вывести слова в обратном алфавитном порядке.

Comment: количество согласных не в одном слове. я описался. то есть если число у меня 5, а ввожу слова "арбуз яблоко", то выведутся слова "яблоко арбуз"

Comment: Приведите условие задачи точно так, как оно было сформулировано.

Comment: "Выведите на экран все слова строки, в которых количество согласных букв превышает вводимое с клавиатуры число,
в обратном алфавитному порядке" - полное условие задачи